# jquery table in typeScript

Tags: jquery, typescript, datatables, typescript1.6

I am really new in the Microsoft Power BI.

I have search a lot how can i insert a data table in the power BI, envirment.

i have tested in the init function just to say hello world

```
public init(options: VisualInitOptions): void {
    this.element = options.element;
    this.element.text('Hello World 0').css('font-size: 40px;')
}
```

And it works fine !

So my question is

**How to insert a jquery datatable in typeScript !**

Do anyone knows any answer or solution !

Comment: You can get the [typedefs](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/jquery.dataTables) for jquery datatable and use it, just install it using tsd command. `tsd install jquery.dataTables --save`